# Netbeans is so slow while developing PHP script

Tags: java, php, netbeans, ubuntu, performance

i'm using Netbeans on Ubuntu, when i write `top` command i notice that Java causes like 100%+ cpu usage. Is there anything to do to speed up Netbeans ? can i download another JRE on ubuntu to speed it up (i'm using OpenJDK).

Thanks .

Comment: A well known problem with both Netbeans and Eclipse and many other IDEs. If you want something fast you will need to pay for it: [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).

Answer (score 5):

Another item that helps me, apart from replacing OpenJDK with SunJDK is the "Scanning Sources"  which can be disabled if you goto `Tools -> Options -> Misc -> Files` and uncheck the Enable "auto-scanning" of sources.

I am not 100% sure what that option does, but it speeds up my projects. Also I would try NetBeans 7, they have made massive leaps and bounds in the newer versions from the older (not knowing what version you are using).

Answer (score 3):

I would:

- Replace OpenJDK with Sun's JDK. OpenJDK's performance is still not upto par.
- I would read [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/kto/entry/why_is_netbeans_so_slow) (a bit dated, but most of works with some changes).

Comment: how to replace openJdk with Sun Jdk in ubuntu? simply install Sun Jdk?

Comment: Yes. See mario's post. Or, to cut it short: sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's well known that Netbeans runs slower with OpenJDK.

Your question has been answered on AskUbuntu before:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/5567/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk

Enable the partner repository and then install Sun Java with:

```
 sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```